# Orthogonal Complement of Orthogonal Complement equals to closure of span

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

Let $X$ is any inner product space and $A \subset X$

> Show that $A^{\bot \bot} = \overline {spanA}$ (closure of $spanA$)

I should show $A^{\bot \bot} \subseteq \overline {spanA}$ and $A^{\bot \bot} \supseteq \overline {spanA}$

I have tried to use sequences for $A^{\bot \bot} \supseteq \overline {spanA}$ side but I couldn’t use. I’m really stuck. I need any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: If $\{x_n\}\subset {\text span}A$ and $x_n\to x\not\in {\text span}A$ then since $x_n\in A^{\perp\perp}$ and the inner product is continuous, then $x\in A^{\perp\perp}$. Really, in this case $\forall y\in A^{\perp}$, $(x_n,y)\to (x,y)$ and, thus, $x\in A^{\perp\perp}$. Finally, tha closure of span$A\subset A^{\perp\perp}$.

Comment: @pabodu Thanks a lot sir. what can I say for the other side? There is no information about set $A$. If it is not countable can I say write span of it?

Comment: @pabodu could you please write or give a link for detailed proof if it is not too much trouble for you.

Comment: my proof above is detailed for that inclusion. I can add only $0=(x_n,y)\to(x,y)$ implies $(x,y)=0$ and, thus, $x\perp A^\perp$. Consequently, $x\in A^{\perp\perp}$ and, thus, $\overline{span}\,A\subset A^{\perp\perp}$.

Comment: @pabodu I couldn’t catch why $x_n \in A^{\perp\perp}$ Isn’t it a sequence of set $spanA$? And actually the other side namely $A^{\perp\perp} \subseteq \overline{spanA}$ is more difficult for me since I have no info about set $A$

Comment: Are you assuming a *complete* inner product space? If you're not, then there is no reason to have equality of the two sets.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts no any inner product space

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Is it wrong?

Comment: @user519955 $x_n\in A$. Then $x_n\in A^{\perp\perp}$. Here and above for simplicity I write $A$ instead of span$A$.